# How can I pass a string to AWS redshift user defined function?

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I want to create a user defined function to implement the functionality of IFNULL as in mySQL.

```
    create function IFNULL (a varchar, b varchar)
      returns varchar
    stable
    as $$
      if a == NULL:
        return b
    $$ language plpythonu;
```

But this expects b to be a table name and supplying string throws error.How can I change the argument so as to receive a constant(string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was not quite right, try this

```
create or replace function f_null(a varchar, b varchar)
  returns varchar
stable
as $$
  if a == '' or a is None:
    return b
  else:
    return a
$$ language plpythonu;
```

then to test

```
select f_null(null,'sdf');
select f_null('','sdf');
select f_null('validstr','sdf');
```

Alternatively, why not just use the inbuilt function "coalesce"

if you don't want to replace a blank string use:

```
select coalesce(null,'sdf');
```